# Java MYSQL Connection Exception

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a MYSQL web server that I'm using for an app and I can't seem to connect to it through Java. I have the .jar file added and everything, my password is stored on my pc the day I created it and my username is correct as well. I'm getting an exception saying it cannot create a connection to the Database server. Any idea why I would get this error

FYI - Changed the password and name for security reasons

```
    try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx:3306/kospotco_DoIT", "user", "pass");

            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

            while (result.next()){
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getString(0) + result.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException x) {
            Toast.makeText(this, x.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.taskit.Login.onClick(Login.java:31)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.421 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.422 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:119)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.423 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:    ... 20 more
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:1012)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.configureSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:95)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:148)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
2021-09-16 20:49:54.424 18845-18845/com.taskit W/System.err:    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Does your db server allow remote connections?

Comment: As far as I am aware yes

Comment: As of now I am getting a Communications link failure

Comment: Do you need to be on any vpn for the database to connect? Can you connect to that database manually without the java code?

Comment: I have the hosting platform open that I'm using for it if that's what you mean

Comment: No I do not have to be on a vpn

Comment: Usually a mysql install defaults to only allow localhost connections and not remote. Can you look at the mysqld.cnf file and check the value for the "bind-address" just to verify its not set to 127.0.0.1.  Also, is port 3306 open on your firewall?

Comment: `I'm getting an exception ...`, so post the stack trace.

Comment: I had a web based mysql database that I used before, so I just used a normal connection string didn't have any issues before, I don't have a .cnf file

Comment: @PeterMmm As of now it is a Communications link failure exception

Comment: So this is Android, mark your question with `android`. For the exception, please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063686/android-error-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denie

Comment: @PeterMmm What does socket exception have to do with a mysql connection

Comment: You connect to MySQL over network.

Comment: Yes but has nothing to do with a socket exception, I'm not using a socket connection anywhere

Comment: This is "the good" of a Java stack trace. It shows you from where the error bubbles up to your app. Of course, you are using sockets, but not directly, The JDBC driver hides this from you, but makes use of network sockets.

Comment: Did you try a database tool like Toad. There must be a user for that domain xxxxx. (grant)

Comment: @JoopEggen xxxxx is a replacement for the connection ip, for security reasons

Comment: Users for the database has already been created on the platform I'm using as well as hosts. I'm using phpMyAdmin as the platform for the database

Comment: FYI: As it appears that you are running JDBC on Android, please read [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004).